# Code for syncing lives in resume and new game

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an Android Application Game about Suubtraction .. In the Home screen you can see three button the Play Options and Exit . if I click Play it will go to the Main Screen or the Playing field.. you can go back to the home screen by clicking the menu button at the playscreen .. after clicking the menu button .. the play button will dissappear and resume button and newgame button will appear.. Features of the game is that we got a timer .. if you are in the Play screen the game automatically started .. you got three lives . if the times runs out you loses a life .. if you got the wrong answer you loses a life .. if you loses all lives the game is over and a dialogbox will pop up they want to try again or not ....giving the answer is an input type ... My problem is that i am having a hard time syncing the life in resume and new game ..Can someone help me

```
EditText edit;
TextView first;
TextView second;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
TextView time;
TextView lvl;
TextView scored;
public static int linked = 0;
public static int resumelevel;
public static int resumescore;
public static int randomnumber1;
public static int randomnumber2;
public static int resumelife;
public static int level2resume;
public static int resumestatus;
public static int one;
public static int two;
public static int scoring =0;
public static int leveling =0;
public static int level2 = 1;
public static int rand1 = 3;
public static int rand2 =3;
public static int life =0;
public static int status =0;
public int g1,g2,ans;

public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public static int what = 0;
public static int bkgchecked = 0;
private int length = 0 ;
public static MediaPlayer wrong;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        } finally {
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
    length = 0;
    bkgchecked =0;
    MainActivity.maintoplay = 1;
    Intent intent1= new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happy);
    wrong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wrong);
    if (linked == 1){
        scoring = resumescore;
        leveling = resumelevel;
        rand1 = randomnumber1;
        rand2 = randomnumber2;
        status = resumestatus;
        level2 = level2resume;
        life = resumelife;
        linked =0;
    }
    if(life == 0){
        if (status == 0) {
            if (scoring ==0) {
                leveling = 1;
                level2 = 1;
                rand1 = 3;
                rand2 = 3;
                life = 0;
                status = 0;
                scoring =0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(life == 1) {
        findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        life =1;
    }
    if(life == 2){
        findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.img_2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        life =2;
    }
    first = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Num1);
    second = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Num2);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    lvl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
    String ll = String.valueOf(leveling);
    lvl.setText(ll);
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    String sc = String.valueOf(scoring);
    scored.setText(sc);
    Random rand = new Random();
    one = rand.nextInt(rand1) + 1;
    two = rand.nextInt(rand2) + 1;
    if (one >= two){
        String myString = String.valueOf(one);
        String myString1 = String.valueOf(two);
        first.setText(myString);
        second.setText(myString1);
    }else{
        String myString = String.valueOf(two);
        String myString1 = String.valueOf(one);
        first.setText(myString);
        second.setText(myString1);
    }
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(11 * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilfinished) {

            time.setText("" + millisUntilfinished / 1000);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
                life = life+1;
            if (life == 1) {
                findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        countDownTimer.start();
            }
            if(life == 2) {
                findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.img_2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
            if (life == 3){
                MainActivity.linken=0;
                linked =0;
                leveling =1;
                level2 = 1;
                rand1 = 3;
                rand2 =3;
                status =0;
                resumescore =0;
                resumelevel = 1;
                randomnumber1 = 3;
                randomnumber2 = 3;
                resumestatus = 0;
                level2resume  = 1;
                resumelife = 0;
                linked =0;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                findViewById(R.id.img_1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.img_2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
                builder.setMessage("GAME OVER                                                                     Your Score is :"+scoring);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        MainActivity.maintoplay = 0;
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                            } finally {
                                mediaPlayer = null;
                            }
                        }
                        scoring =0;
                        leveling =1;
                        level2 = 1;
                        rand1 = 3;
                        rand2 =3;
                        life =0;
                        status =0;
                        length = 0;
                        bkgchecked =0;
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                            } finally {
                                mediaPlayer = null;
                            }
                        }
                        scoring =0;
                        leveling =1;
                        level2 = 1;
                        rand1 = 3;
                        rand2 =3;
                        life =0;
                        status =0;
                        length = 0;
                        bkgchecked =0;
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainScreen.class));
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
    if (bkgchecked == 0){
        findViewById(R.id.btn_onPlay).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_offPlay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    Button clickmenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Menu_Main_Screen);
    clickmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use Intent
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                } finally {
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
            resumelevel = Integer.parseInt(lvl.getText().toString());
            resumescore = Integer.parseInt(scored.getText().toString());
            resumestatus =status;
            randomnumber1 =rand1;
            randomnumber2 = rand2;
            resumelife =life;
            level2resume =level2;
            length = 0;
            bkgchecked =0;
            linked =0;
            MainActivity.maintoplay = 1;
            Intent intent1= new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });

    Button clickon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_onPlay);
    clickon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use Intent
            if (bkgchecked == 1) {
                bkgchecked = 0;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                View b = findViewById(R.id.btn_offPlay);
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                View ba = findViewById(R.id.btn_onPlay);
                ba.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                what = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    Button clicksubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    clicksubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use Intent
            if ((edit.getText().toString()).isEmpty()== false) {
                g1 = Integer.parseInt(first.getText().toString());
                g2 = Integer.parseInt(second.getText().toString());
                ans = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
                int rans = g1 - g2;
                if (rans == ans) {
                    CountDownTimer image = new CountDownTimer(2*500,500) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            findViewById(R.id.imagecorrect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            findViewById(R.id.imagecorrect).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    };
                    image.start();
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    one = rand.nextInt(rand1) + 1;
                    two = rand.nextInt(rand2) + 1;
                    if (one >= two) {
                        String myString = String.valueOf(one);
                        String myString1 = String.valueOf(two);
                        first.setText(myString);
                        second.setText(myString1);
                    } else {
                        String myString = String.valueOf(two);
                        String myString1 = String.valueOf(one);
                        first.setText(myString);
                        second.setText(myString1);
                    }
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    status = status + 1;
                    scoring = scoring + 10;
                    String scores = String.valueOf(scoring);
                    scored.setText(scores);
                    if (status == 10) {
                        leveling = leveling + 1;
                        level2 = 2;
                        String levl = String.valueOf(leveling);
                        lvl.setText(levl);
                    }
                    if (level2 == 2) {
                        rand1 = rand1 + 1;
                        rand2 = rand2 + 1;
                        status = 1;
                        level2 = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    final CountDownTimer images = new CountDownTimer(2*500,500) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            findViewById(R.id.imagewrong).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            findViewById(R.id.imagewrong).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    };
                    images.start();
                    life= life +1;
                    if (life == 1) {
                        findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        countDownTimer.start();

                    }
                    if (life == 2) {
                        findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.img_2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        countDownTimer.start();

                    }
                    if(life == 3){
                        MainActivity.linken=0;
                        linked =0;
                        leveling =1;
                        level2 = 1;
                        rand1 = 3;
                        rand2 =3;
                        status =0;
                        linked =0;
                        resumescore =0;
                        resumelevel = 1;
                        randomnumber1 = 3;
                        randomnumber2 = 3;
                        resumestatus = 0;
                        level2resume  = 1;
                        resumelife = 0;
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                        findViewById(R.id.img_1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.img_2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.img_3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
                        builder.setMessage("GAME OVER                                                                      Your Score is :"+scoring);
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                                        mediaPlayer.release();
                                    } finally {
                                        mediaPlayer = null;
                                    }
                                }
                                scoring =0;
                                leveling =1;
                                level2 = 1;
                                rand1 = 3;
                                rand2 =3;
                                life =0;
                                status =0;
                                length = 0;
                                bkgchecked = 0;
                                MainActivity.maintoplay = 0;
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    try {
                                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                                        mediaPlayer.release();
                                    } finally {
                                        mediaPlayer = null;
                                    }
                                }
                                scoring =0;
                                leveling =1;
                                level2 = 1;
                                rand1 = 3;
                                rand2 =3;
                                life =0;
                                status =0;
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainScreen.class));
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                }
                edit.setText("");
            }else{
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
                builder.setMessage("PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        countDownTimer.start();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
        });




    Button clickoff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_offPlay);
    clickoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use Intent
            if(bkgchecked == 0) {
                if (length != 0) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        View b = findViewById(R.id.btn_onPlay);
                        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        View ba = findViewById(R.id.btn_offPlay);
                        ba.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        bkgchecked = 1;
                        what = 1;
                    }
                }else{
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    View b = findViewById(R.id.btn_onPlay);
                    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    View ba = findViewById(R.id.btn_offPlay);
                    ba.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bkgchecked = 1;
                    what = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Android application lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Basically you need to save the number of lives in the `onPause()` method which is called when the user leaves your activity, like:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();

lives = your_lives_method();

}
```

Now you can edit the `onResume()` method to use the `lives` variable to find out the number of lives the user had, like:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

main_lives = lives;

}
```

Comment: what happens when if i clicked the new game instead of the resume button? does this methods still gonna run right .. so the lives will still have the current value .. so there might be a problem at the lives in the new game?

Comment: You must have a method for initializing a new game. Call that method in `onCreate()`. You can use a `boolean` variable to check if the game has been run for the first time in `onResume()`, just set it true whenever a new game is run.

Comment: can you show me how to know if the game was run for the first time?

Comment: I have provided the answer that you required. You can't expect me to implement it for you as well.